# Replace substring after second occurence of character bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace, substring

I have this string "foo1.0_1.0", which I want to increment by 1, based on the number after the second '.', which can be more than one digit.

Here is my attempt:

```
str="foo1.0_1.0"
version="${str##*.}"                 # gives 0
new_version="$((version + 1))"       # gives 1

echo "${str/${str##*.}/$new_version}"    # gives foo1.1_1.0 (desired: foo1.0_1.1)
```

since it will take the result of `${str##*.}` as the pattern.

How to achieve this? More generally, how to replace a substring after the second occurrence of a certain character (dot in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you can use dot as delimiter and increment 3rd field:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$3++} 1' <<< "$str"
```

> foo1.0_1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sed` like:

```
#!/bin/bash
str=foo1.0_1.0
header=$(echo $str | sed -n 's/\(.*\.\)[0-9]*/\1/p')
ending=$(echo $str | sed -n 's/.*\.\([0-9]\)/\1/p')
ending=$((ending + 1))
echo $header$ending
```

Comment: It works, but I am not sure from [regex101](https://regex101.com/) what you are doing there, can you please explain? :)

Comment: Yes, in `s/\(.*\.\)[0-9]*/\1/p` you are saving in a register `\1` of `sed` the values between `\(...\)`, this corresponds to the header part without the ending number (`foo_1.0_1.`). In the second regexp it is doing the same but for the ending number (`0`).

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, but why do need \ between the star and the dot? Also, why a / after the second star?

Comment: No, problem I am not an expert in `sed` but generally the commands in `sed` are `sed -e 's/ ... / ... /p'` . Here `s` means **substitute** and `p` **print**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this method which is a modification of your code

```
str="foo1.0_1.0"
version="${str##*.}"                 # gives 0
new_version="$((version + 1))"       # gives 1
echo "${str%${version}}${new_version}"
# gives foo1.0_1.1
```

Comment: @gsamaras It removes the version from the str and then appends the new version to it

Answer (score 1):

With read and a heredoc :

```
str="foo1.0_1.17"
while IFS='.' read a b c
  do
    echo $a"."$b"."$((c+1))
  done <<EOF
$str
EOF
```